Python Knative func with gRPC and Kourier
I am trying to deploy a simple gRPC Knative func on Kubernetes in Python, but the configuration does not seem to work. I only found func templates for HTTP. I am using Kourier. I don't want to use Knative serving instead of func. But if a Knative func extension that supports gRPC exists, please let me know.
I tried to set the invocation format in func.yaml to grpc, and set healthEndpoints to {}, however I still get aggressive probe error (failed 202 times): Get "http://127.0.0.1:8080/health/readiness": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused.
This is my func.yaml configuration:
specVersion: 0.25.0
name: sample-grpc
namespace: default
runtime: python
registry: registry
image: registry:latest
imageDigest: 12345
buildpacks: []
builder: pack
volumes: []
buildEnvs: []
envs: []
annotations: {}
options: {}
labels: []
healthEndpoints: {}
created: 2024-04-17T09:20:37.358544819+02:00
invocation:
  format: grpc

This is my func.py:
import argparse
from concurrent import futures
import logging
from time import sleep

import grpc

import greet_pb2
import greet_pb2_grpc

_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24


class Greeter(greet_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):
    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        logging.info(f'Request name[{request.name}]')
        return greet_pb2.HelloReply(message=f'Hello {request.name}')


def serve(port):
    logging.info(f'Starting gRPC server on port[{port}]')
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    server.add_insecure_port(f'[::]:{port}')
    greet_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)

    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=50051)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    serve(args.port)

This is the Procfile:
web: python func.py
I try to deploy the function and then the ksvc service never gets ready, the error is the one from above.
